# Node js Printing info from JSON file using a function from another file V2.0

Tags: node.js

This is a continuation from another question I asked earlier [Node.js Printing info from JSON file using a function from another JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779282/node-js-printing-info-from-json-file-using-a-function-from-another-js-file/46779552?noredirect=1#comment80506048_46779552)

In my previous question I had problems in calling a function from my data-service.js file that printed all the items in my JSON array, and had it resolved, but now I'm struggling in doing something similar in printing only the employees from my JSON array that I specify through the url. For example http://localhost:8080/employeesstatus=5 would print only the employee with a status of 5 however nothing is getting printed

SERVER.JS

```
var HTTP_PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var express = require('express');
var data = require('./data-service');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var object = require('./data-service');

console.log("Express http server listening on 8080");

//app.get('/employees', function(req,res){
 //   return object.getAllEmployees()
 //   .then((response) => res.send(response))
//});  //QUESION FROM PREVIOUS POST WHICH WAS RESOLVED


app.get('/employees:?status=:value', function(req,res){
return object.getEmployeesByStatus(req.params.value)
  .then((response) => res.send(response));

});
```

DATA SERVICE.JS

```
var employees = [];
var departments = [];
var error = 0;
var fs = require("fs");


function initialize(){

employees = fs.readFileSync("./data/employees.json", 'utf8', function(err, data){
    if(err){
        error = 1;
    }
    employees = JSON.parse(data);

});


departments = fs.readFileSync("./data/department.json", 'utf8', 
function(err, data){
      if(err){
            error = 1;
      }
      departments = JSON.parse(data);

  });
}
function check() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

      if (error === 0){
          resolve("Success");

      }
      else if(error === 1){
         reject("unable to read file");
      }
  })     
};

var getAllEmployees = function(){

  return check().then(function(x){
    console.log(x);
    console.log(employees);
    return employees;

  }).catch(function(x){
    console.log("No results returned");
  });
}

var getEmployeesByStatus = function (status){
return check().then(function(x){
var employees2 = JSON.parse(employees);
for (var i = 0; i<employees2.length; i++){
    if (employees2[i].status == status){
        return console.log(employees2[i]);
      }
  }       
  }).catch(function(){
      console.log("no results returned");
  })
}

module.exports.getAllEmployees = getAllEmployees;
module.exports.getEmployeesByStatus = getEmployeesByStatus;
```

---

The 2 functions in question

```
app.get('/employees:?status=:value', function(req,res){
return object.getEmployeesByStatus(req.params.value)
  .then((response) => res.send(response));

});

var getEmployeesByStatus = function (status){
return check().then(function(x){
var employees2 = JSON.parse(employees);
for (var i = 0; i<employees2.length; i++){
    if (employees2[i].status == status){
        return employees2[i];
    }
}       
}).catch(function(){
    console.log("no results returned");
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should replace /employees route with the following

```
app.get('/employees/status=:value', function(req,res){
 return object.getEmployeesByStatus(req.params.value)
 .then((response) => res.send(response));
});
```

You are able to access using http://localhost:8080/employees/status=5

2) Return employees2[i] instead of console.log(employees2[i]).

Comment: Now, access http://localhost:8080/employees?status=5 endpoint. It should return employee with status 5.

Comment: Anything after ? will be constructed as query object. If you want to add status to path param, we should do it in a different way. I will update now.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to get it done using the app.get('/employees:?status=:value', function(req,res){... function

Comment: hmm. It doesn't seem to work. I'm no longer greeted with an error message however nothing is getting printed

Comment: Are you seeing employees2[i] value when logging?

Comment: what's your employees object?

Comment: It's just a simple JSON array

Comment: I see your status value as a string in the old post. I hope you tried `http://localhost:8080/employees/status=Full Time`

Comment: Yes your right, however it only returns once and then ends when it should print dozens of results

Comment: I'm thinking that I have to add the values to a new array and then return the array

Comment: Your getEmployeesByStatus function returns first matching employee. If you want all employees matching the criteria you should create a new array and return it.

Comment: `employees2.filter((i) => i.status === status)` returns array of objects.

Comment: You don't need for loop. Just return above statement.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the question by creating a new array called order and just pushed the elements of employees2[i] to it and then returned it. You have been very helpful